# Creating an API in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

How should I create my symfony 4 project if I just want to build an API?

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

Is this line the correct line to use or do I have to include something like

```
 composer create-project symfony/api-skeleton my-project
```

??

Answer (score 2):

" api-skeleton " is  not stable with symfony 4 
 you can use

```
 composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

or you can create a usual symfony4 project with:

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton my-project
```

Comment: Thank you for the post, but both of your examples are the same "website-skeleton".

Comment: One of the options should be: `composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project`

Answer (score 0):

To create an API with symfony 4, use the following command:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```